# Nigamantha Maha Desikan

Tags: puranas, ranganatha, vedanta-desika

Nigamantha Maha Desikan was a great Vaishnava acharya. He has composed many slokas. What are the titles given to him by the Srirangam Divya dampathis Lord Ranganatha and Goddess Ranganayaki  for which slokas? If puranic reference is there it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Nigamantha Maha Desikan(1268-1370 CE) was a Srivaishnava Guru lived post Sri Ramanuja Period.

Two titles were given by both Lord Ranganatha and his consort.

1. `Sarvathanthra swathanthrar` - which means that he is master of all
   arts, crafts. This title conferred upon him by Sri Ranganayaki
   Thayar.
2. `Vedanthacharya` -  title conferred upon him by Sri Ranganathan

**Sources**

http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/oppiliappan/archives/oct03/msg00128.html
http://srivedantadesikan.blogspot.in/2007/02/swami-at-srirangam.html

Comment: @blackcaps--For which stotras he was conferred? Not only one or two slokas he composed. There is a stotra nidhi.